# How can I save user data in a Firebase database if I don't have unique, user registration

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Concept:**

Imagine an App that tracks the price of a stock, and when the price dips below a certain point, the user will get a notification.

**How I have it set up:**

I have a Python back-end that tracks the price and updates the Firebase Database witch current prices.

I am also using Xcode, so I used Firebase Cloud Functions (FCF) and Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for Push Notifications.

I decide the price-limit from the App, click a button which saves that price in the Firebase Database.
Whenever the stock goes below that price, a push notification will be issued through the FCF/FCM.

**My Problem:**

I've built my app so far to do exactly this, but I reached a point where I realized that any time a user changes the alert-point price, it changes for all the users, across all devices.
How can I make so that each user can set his own price without affecting other users?

**Notes:**

1. There is no user registration required, as I don't feel like I have the need to do that, and I would really like to keep it that way if possible.
2. Idea: since I'm using the "Device Token" to issue notifications, and they are unique to each device, is there a way to capitalize on this, and save the user's target-price using device tokens somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Device Token". Just make sure to "clean" it up if it has some chars that are forbidden for Firebase Database keys `. $ # [ ] / or any ASCII control characters (0x00 - 0x1F and 0x7F)` and that it's not bigger than `768 Bytes`

You could also use the autogenerated uid when adding data to a list of values and store that in your app.